# Determining area enclosed by given curves

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, curves

[[image: Purple line represents <span class=]$e^x$ and black line represents $y=\sin(x)$ " />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52D8b.png)

Hi I'm doing a question in the textbook that requires me to find the area enclosed by the given curves. The curves are $y=\sin(x)$ $y=e^x$ $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. From these points/equations I don't know what region I should integrate to determine the area. Could someone give me an idea on how to begin.(ie where the enclosed region is) Thank you!

On the graph the purple line represents $e^x$ and black line represents $y=\sin(x)$

Comment: Add the graphs of the $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$ to your picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sketch of the region:
[image]

Remember that $\color{red}{x=0}$ and $\color{green}{x= \frac{\pi}{2}}$ are the vertical lines that pass through $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ on the $x$-axis, drawn in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ and $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ respectively in the diagram above.

Once you draw these vertical lines the region enclosed by all four lines becomes clear.